# altair histogram chart with transform aggregate can't properly overlay a global mean

Tags: histogram, transform, mean, altair

I am trying to create a histogram with a global mean. The source table needs to be transformed first using transform_aggregate. But when I add the mean to the chart, the histogram is gone and the chart is only showing the mean line.  Can someone help me with it? Here is the code.

```python
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.movies.url

base = alt.Chart(source).transform_aggregate(agg='mean(IMDB_Rating)',groupby=['Distributor'])

bar = base.mark_bar().encode( x=alt.X('agg:Q', bin=alt.Bin(step=0.5), ),y='count()')

rule = base.mark_rule(color='red').encode(x='mean(agg):Q',size=alt.value(5))

bar + rule
```

[image: See the output chart here]

Answer (score 2):

It seems that having the aggregate transform present in two layers is somehow corrupting the data stream; this seems like a bug. I was able to find a way to work around it, by attaching the transform to the top level chart rather than to each individual layer:

```python
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.movies.url

bar = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
  x=alt.X('agg:Q', bin=alt.Bin(step=0.5), ),
  y='count()'
)

rule = alt.Chart(source).mark_rule(color='red').encode(
  x='mean(agg):Q',size=alt.value(5)
)

alt.layer(bar, rule).transform_aggregate(
  agg='mean(IMDB_Rating)',
  groupby=['Distributor']
)
```

[image]